# Is there an alternative when using supervisor with Gunicorn?

Tags: gunicorn, supervisord

I am creating a Flask app and I using Nginx and Gunicorn inside a virtual enviroment. When I start Gunicorn, `gunicorn app:app` everything works fine. Then when I activate the Supervisor to keep gunicorn active, it gives me a 500 error. I am reading in my log in var/log/ that is error happens when I try to open a file that should have been created after `subprocess.run(command, capture_output=True, shell=True)` So this line is not being executed correctly.

Is there an alternative to supervisor to keep my app running when my putty is closed?

Thanks.

Comment: After a lot of research, I found that it is possible to use systemd, Upstart, Procfile and Runit, here the docuentation. https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html. However, I wanted to find a simpler way which gunicorn has. when you call gunicorn like: gunicorn app:app. You can simply use --daemon. In th way you can make gunicorn app:app --daemon. This will make that your system continues running. It might not be the best option but since I am still in development it is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here.

https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html

It says that one good option is using Runit.

EDIT:

I ended up using the Gunicorn function called --deamon. It is similar and makes everything much simpler.